# parsing html using custom designed specific xpath scripts per site in java

Tags: java, html, parsing, xpath

I am writing an application where we need to monitor about 5000+ web sites on a regular basis and populate a db with specific content such as author, title, date, abstract, content etc. Since we are looking for very specific and accurate content we are planning to use custom designed XPath scripts per site / page type and use such scripts to drive a parser.

Its a Java based application.

Is there any ready library in Java to do this ? We are well versed with JTidy but it doesn't do exactly what we want.

Is there any better approach that you may recommend ?

Please note - I have gone through tons of html parsing / XPath related questions and didn't find anything that answers this question.

thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

[jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) can do the parsing and has a [selector-syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) (similar to jQuery, so if you know that you're flying) to easily locate nodes.

If you want something to do the HTML monitoring and downloading, then I'd use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/).

Comment: Thanks Paul... We will attempt building our Xpath script driver and give JSoup a shot. Though we will possibly stick to Selenium for scraping since we have good expertise on it.